# How to include Drawer Navigator inside Stack Navigator inside Tab Navigator with a single navigation file

Tags: android, ios, react-native

First of all, yes i'm aware there are many answers related with this question, but i found this specific way to make my navigation in react-native 0.60, the thing is, i haven't figure it out yet, and i don't want to scrape this navigation method to test a different one, this is the navigation file, not sure how to put the drawer inside where or how.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);

const VacationsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Vacations: VacationsScreen,
    Request: RequestScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#0091EA",
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFF",
      title: "Vacaciones"
    }
  }
);

const HourAllocationsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HourAllocations: HourAllocationsScreen,
    Allocations: AllocationsScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#0091EA"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFF",
      title: "Registro"
    }
  }
);

const ExpensesStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Expenses: ExpensesScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#0091EA"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFF",
      title: "Rendir"
    }
  }
);

const CertificatesStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Certificates: CertificatesScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#0091EA"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFF",
      title: "Certificados"
    }
  }
);

const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Vacations: VacationsStack,
    HourAllocations: HourAllocationsStack,
    Expenses: ExpensesStack,
    Certificates: CertificatesStack
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: () => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          return (
            <Icon name="home" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
          );
        }
        if (routeName === "Vacations") {
          return (
            <Icon5 name="sun" solid size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
          );
        }
        if (routeName === "Expenses") {
          return (
            <Icon5 name="plane" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
          );
        }
        if (routeName === "Certificates") {
          return(
            <Icon name="bill" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
          );
        }
        if (routeName === "HourAllocations") {
          return(
            <Icon name="clock" solid size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
          );
        }
      }
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#FF6F00",
      inactiveTintColor: "#263238"
    },
  }
);

const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  User: UserScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen
})

export default createAppContainer(MainApp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `tab navigator` in the `drawer Navigator`, and put the `drawer Navigator` in the `stack navigator`.

```js
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  User: UserScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
  MainTab : MainApp
},
{
 initialRouteName : 'MainTab'
})

...
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen: DrawerNavigation
  },
  {
   initialRouteName : 'MainScreen' 
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

Comment: @NicolasSilva This is actually the way I used it.

Comment: let me check if it works, and i'll response you, thanks in advance

Comment: not sure why isn't working, maybe i missed something, also, i just noticed the header was pushed downwards

Comment: not really, not a single error, but the this.props.navigation.navigate("MainTab") is not opening the drawer, not sure if this is my mistake, but that's how i navigate through my screens, at least the stack is working normally with your method, is just that drawer isn't opening

Comment: You can execute two commands to open the drawer. `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();` OR `this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());`

Comment: it worked, it finally worked xd tho i'm having issues with the header, but that's a different story, i'll check yours as the answer, once again, thanks for everything dude, and thanks for having the time to chat right here

Comment: not sure if you can help me with a little thing, there is a header in the top, and i don't know where is coming from, i checked every navigator with a header: null, and still no clue where it is

Comment: @NicolasSilva Are you saying heather is null but he remains? Please leave a link after posting any new questions.

Comment: i posted the problem in the main post, with a screenshot included

Comment: @NicolasSilva You shouldn't post new problems here. Put it up as a new question.

Comment: i posted the new issue, hope you can check it out too, thanks in advance